# Trying to create login script for myBB forum

Tags: php, sql, database

Im trying to create a login script to connect with my myBB forum Database and echo true or false whether the username and password is correct, but I keep getting this error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function escape_string() on a non-object in /home2/tronic/public_html/forum/inc/tronic_login.php on line 76

```
function validate_password_from_username()
{
        $username = $_GET['username'];
        $password = $_GET['password'];

        global $db, $mybb;

        $username = $db->escape_string(my_strtolower($username));
        switch($mybb->settings['username_method'])
        {
                case 0:
                        $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(username)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
                        break;
                case 1:
                        $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(email)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
                        break;
                case 2:
                        $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(username)='".$username."' OR LOWER(email)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
                        break;
                default:
                        $query = $db->simple_select("users", "uid,username,password,salt,loginkey,coppauser,usergroup", "LOWER(username)='".$username."'", array('limit' => 1));
                        break;
        }

        $user = $db->fetch_array($query);
        if(!$user['uid'])
        {
                echo("false");
        }
        else
        {
                echo("true");
        }
}
```

http://pastebin.com/KU130cZE

Comment: Your db connection failed.

Answer (score 0):

In line 8, you're calling `$db->escape_string(my_strtolower($username));`. Problem is: `$db` isn't defined yet, or not an object.

I cannot tell you what it is, as it'S a global variable (bad thing, one should avoid those!), so I cannot tell where it is set and what value it has - but it's clearly not an object, so my best bet is it's either unset/`null`, or `false` because some function that is supposed to set it had an error and returned `false`.